# Python Code for RPM-measurement with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project where I use a photoelectric sensor to detect a reflector attached to a motor axis. Every time the reflector reflects the light from the LED from the sensor it sends a pulse (voltage) to the raspberry pi (with a voltage divider). With some help I've come to the following code and I've noticed that the results that I'm getting are way too high. Anybody got any suggestions on how to improve it? I've seen other examples of RPM code online, but I wanted to learn it myself and the ones that I've found did not use the same method as me. Thanks in advance!

```
import time
from gpiozero import Button

sensor = Button(17) 

i=1 
timestampeven=0 
timestamponeven=0 


def pulsen():
    global i
    global timestampeven
    global timestamponeven
    if (i % 2) ==0:
            timestampeven = time.time_ns()
            i+=1
    elif (i % 2) == 1:
            timestamponeven = time.time_ns()
            i+=1
            periode = timestamponeven-timestampeven
            frequentie = 1/(periode*10e09)
            rpm = frequentie*60
            print("rpm=" + str(rpm))
            print("teller = " +str(i))
            print("periode = " +str(periode))
            print("frequentie = " +str(frequentie))
    
    

sensor.when_pressed = pulsen

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: Maybe you want `1e09` instead of `10e09`?

Comment: Oh and you probably want to divide instead of multiply.